# How to ask the bot to send back more words and not just the first [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i just want to make a google search thing... I have the restof the code to do that i would change the input tag to the message tag or someting

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['a'])
async def on_message(ctx, messages):
  await ctx.send(messages)
```

[what the bot id doing to that code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT3ej.png)

(the code what i wanted to be)

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['google'])
async def on_message(ctx, message):
  googleinput = message
  pgoogleinput = googleinput.replace(" ", "+")
  await ctx.send("https://www.google.com/search?q="+pgoogleinput)
```

Comment: One thing I think that needs to be specified here is that your command name is `on_message`, is this intended? Or are you confusing commands with on_message.
Generally discord.py takes the function name to be the invocation name of the command and adds aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add `*` before the argument you want to consume fully.
basically, `*` collects all the positional arguments in a tuple.
So the code will look like:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['a'])
async def on_message(ctx, *, messages):
  await ctx.send(messages)
```

Similarly, for second code, it will look like:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['google'])
async def on_message(ctx, *, message):
  googleinput = message
  pgoogleinput = googleinput.replace(" ", "+")
  await ctx.send("https://www.google.com/search?q="+pgoogleinput)
```

These are mentioned in the python documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass the message as a keyword-only arguments, thanks to this discord.py will parse all the arguments as one string

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['google'])
async def on_message(ctx, *, message):
  googleinput = message
  pgoogleinput = googleinput.replace(" ", "+")
  await ctx.send("https://www.google.com/search?q="+pgoogleinput)
```